# JUnit y webflux da el error org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: No suitable writer found for part

Tags: java, upload, spring-webflux

Buenas tardes estoy desarrollando una funcionalidad en java 8 webflux, intento generar 1 test a nivel de Controller sin embargo cuando intento ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

```
'
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: No suitable writer found for part: file
    
at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.encodePart(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:260) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
.
.
.
'
```

Adjunto codigo de test:

```
        MultipartBodyBuilder multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("file", new ClassPathResource("ejemplo.csv"))
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        
        Mockito.when(salespointService.importData(any(FilePart.class))).thenReturn(Flux.just(""));

        webClient.post()
                .uri("/upload")
                .header("x", "x")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(multipartBodyBuilder.build()))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
```

Adjunto codigo de Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Mono<List<String>> importData(@RequestPart("file") FilePart filePartMono) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: tal parece que tu `multipartBodyBuilder`  no tiene contenido, es decir podrias tratar de crearlo con algo tipo `bodyBuilder.asyncPart("file", file.content(), DataBuffer.class)`

Comment: Muchas gracias si se trato de eso. Ya lo pude resolver :)